# If all sub-populations are normal, will this population normal?

Tags: normal-distribution, population

1. If all sub-populations are normal, will this population normal?
2. What is this theorem called?

Comment: What do you mean by a "subpopulation"?   Indeed, what do you mean by "normal"?  One would suppose, from the latter, that you are asking about a Normal *distribution* or Normal *random variable,* but then what would a "subpopulation" of one of those possibly be??